# Solving (BEq a a0 = BTrue \/ BEq a a0 = BFalse) in Coq

Tags: coq, proof

`(BEq a a0 = BTrue \/ BEq a a0 = BFalse)` is either true or false since `a==a0` or `a!=a0`. However, I'm not sure how I can get Coq to see this. Here is my complete proof window:

`4 subgoal
a : aexp
a0 : aexp
st : state
______________________________________(1/4)
(BEq a a0 = BTrue \/ BEq a a0 = BFalse) \/
(exists b' : bexp, BEq a a0 / st ==>b b')`

Any suggestions on how to proceed?

---

Definitions:

```
Inductive bexp : Type :=
    BTrue : bexp
  | BFalse : bexp
  | BEq : aexp -> aexp -> bexp
  | BLe : aexp -> aexp -> bexp
  | BNot : bexp -> bexp
  | BAnd : bexp -> bexp -> bexp
.
Inductive aexp : Type :=
    ANum : nat -> aexp
  | AId : id -> aexp
  | APlus : aexp -> aexp -> aexp
  | AMinus : aexp -> aexp -> aexp
  | AMult : aexp -> aexp -> aexp
.

Inductive bstep : state -> bexp -> bexp -> Prop :=
  | BS_Eq : forall st n1 n2,
      (BEq (ANum n1) (ANum n2)) / st ==>b 
      (if (beq_nat n1 n2) then BTrue else BFalse)
  | BS_Eq1 : forall st a1 a1' a2,
      a1 / st ==>a a1' ->
      (BEq a1 a2) / st ==>b (BEq a1' a2)
  | BS_Eq2 : forall st v1 a2 a2',
      aval v1 -> 
      a2 / st ==>a a2' ->
      (BEq v1 a2) / st ==>b (BEq v1 a2')
  | BS_LtEq : forall st n1 n2,
      (BLe (ANum n1) (ANum n2)) / st ==>b 
               (if (ble_nat n1 n2) then BTrue else BFalse)
  | BS_LtEq1 : forall st a1 a1' a2,
      a1 / st ==>a a1' ->
      (BLe a1 a2) / st ==>b (BLe a1' a2)
  | BS_LtEq2 : forall st v1 a2 a2',
      aval v1 ->
      a2 / st ==>a a2' ->
      (BLe v1 a2) / st ==>b (BLe v1 (a2'))
  | BS_NotTrue : forall st,
      (BNot BTrue) / st ==>b BFalse
  | BS_NotFalse : forall st,
      (BNot BFalse) / st ==>b BTrue
  | BS_NotStep : forall st b1 b1',
      b1 / st ==>b b1' ->
      (BNot b1) / st ==>b (BNot b1')
  | BS_AndTrueTrue : forall st,
      (BAnd BTrue BTrue) / st ==>b BTrue
  | BS_AndTrueFalse : forall st,
      (BAnd BTrue BFalse) / st ==>b BFalse
  | BS_AndFalse : forall st b2,
      (BAnd BFalse b2) / st ==>b BFalse
  | BS_AndTrueStep : forall st b2 b2',
      b2 / st ==>b b2' ->
      (BAnd BTrue b2) / st ==>b (BAnd BTrue b2')
  | BS_AndStep : forall st b1 b1' b2,
      b1 / st ==>b b1' ->
      (BAnd b1 b2) / st ==>b (BAnd b1' b2)

  where " t '/' st '==>b' t' " := (bstep st t t').
```

Comment: Can you add the definitions of `BEq`, `aexp`, and your step relation `==>`?

Comment: @Matt Added the definitions

Comment: Can you also add the definitions of ``==>a`` ?

Comment: Well if (as you claim) you can prove that the left statement is true, then use the tactic `left.` to change the goal to that.  (It simply applies the constructor `or_introl`).  And if you haven't proved the statement, you should probably do induction on the terms `a` and `a0`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm fairly certain that this is not provable.  Given your proof context:

```
4 subgoal
a : aexp
a0 : aexp
st : state
______________________________________(1/4)
(BEq a a0 = BTrue \/ BEq a a0 = BFalse) \/
(exists b' : bexp, BEq a a0 / st ==>b b')
```

You need to be able to prove at least one disjunct.  `BEq a a0 = BTrue` is not provable.  `Beq` and `BTrue` are two **different** constructors of the same type, so under Coq's equality, this will never hold.  The same goes for `BEq a a0 = BFalse`.  In fact, I can prove that these things are not equal:

```
Theorem BeqBFalseNeq : forall a a0, BEq a a0 <> BFalse.
Proof.
  intros a a0 contra. inversion contra. 
Qed. 

Theorem BeqBTrueNeq : forall a a0, BEq a a0 <> BTrue.
Proof.
  intros a a0 contra. inversion contra. 
Qed.
```

One might think that `exists b' : bexp, BEq a a0 / st ==>b b'` could be proven, by inducting on `a` and then destructing `a0`.  This would give you a bunch of cases, and you would need to show that for each case you can take a step, however, you will inevitably find yourself in a case where you won't be able to show that a step can be taken.  For example, if you have the case where `a` is `APlus (AId x) (ANum 12)`, and `a0` is some other arbitrary expression, then you will need to show that it is possible for `BEq (APlus (AId x) (ANum 12)) a0` to take a step.  You might think that you can use the `BS_Eq1` rule, however, you have no guarantee that `APlus (AId x) (ANum 12)` can take a step under your `==>a` relation, assuming that to use an id, it needs to be in the current state.  If `x` does not currently exist in the given state, you will not be able to take a step.

Answer (score 1):

Since `BEq` is a constructor of your `bexp` type, there is no reason at first that makes me things your statement is true. This is just a name, like `BLe`, so there is nothing telling Coq that this should be interpreted as the equality over `bexp`. However you might be able to prove your full statement using the description of `bstep`.

At the moment I can't do much more than that, since we lack the definitions of `==>a` (`astep` I presume) and `state`.